# In docusign, how do I close a signed email template

Tags: docusignapi

In docusign, how do I close a signed email template or change the specific style of a signed email template, such as inserting an html tag

I can close the signed message template or change the specific style of the signed message template, such as inserting html tags

Answer (score 0):

https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide&topicId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide.pdf&_LANG=enus

Includes this information:

> Email Resource File Editing Information The email formats are HTML and
> plain text information wrapped in XML and files must follow XML
> standard formats. When you open the resource file you can edit the
> HTML body and plain text body information in the file. When editing
> the HTML body text, DocuSign recommends that you also make the
> corresponding changes to the plain body text. DocuSign sends both in
> an email and some email client software uses the plain text body for
> email preview or when the user chooses not to read as HTML. The email
> templates in the email resource file are used for both web email and
> mobile email. You cannot create separate email templates for web and
> mobile email. DocuSign recommends that you do not change the location
> of buttons in the email text. Modified resource files must be saved as
> xml files. After editing and saving the email resource file, you can
> upload it to the appropriate brand profile. DocuSign recommends that
> you test any resource file changes in your demo account before
> uploading it to production,

Comment: What should I do if I want to change only the email template sent when the signing is complete

Comment: ,I don't want to change all the content of the email, I just want to change the template of the email sent when all the users have signed it and change the style of the email inside

Comment: Can't do that, sorry, one template is used for the entire account, can't have it differently for different envelopes.

Comment: At present, the integration method of our project is as follows: after docusign signing is completed, call the callback interface provided by our web project. If I want to close the docusign signing completed state email and send the signing email in our own callback interface, how should I close the docusign signing completed state email in the setting

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "close the document" if you mean close the window/iframe - that is a regular web thing. If you mean you want to click the "Finish" button for your user - can't do that, user must do it manually.

Comment: One more question, why is there no Go To Admin option in the avatar Settings menu when I click on it

Comment: "Settings" is "Admin" do you not have "Settings" at all?

Comment: Could you please provide me with your email address? I will describe the problem I met in detail

Comment: inbar.gazit@docusign.com

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the state of the envelope by using a webhook. -- See the DocuSign Connect documentation.

Then send your own email when the envelope has completed. (When all signers have signed.)